# php make next set of items on a limited while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

[How to limit items from while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006069/how-to-limit-items-from-while-loop)

relating on the topic above, if example ill be showing the next 10 items on a different block (page or another loop) , what could be the code for that?

Comment: Why don't you do it with the `offset` parameter to the SQL `LIMIT` clause?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't agree with the while loops from your example link. It's a bit outdated in my humble opinion. More common is to pass a limit and offset to some data resource, like a database query with LIMIT 0,10 or LIMIT 10,10 (in MySQL). Then you could just foreach through the entire set, since you'll always get back a maximum of 10.

If you search for something like "PHP MySQL pagination" you'd find a lot of resources on Google explaining this.

Your question is too generic to give you specific answers.